# Bind the position of an element to another element's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, position, element

Is there any way in jQuery to make an element stay at the same position as another element?

Say there is a textbox and a `<span>`. How would one let the `<span>` always overlap the textbox, i.e. have it bound at the same position? Also, when the textbox is moving for any reason, I'd like to have the `<span>` go along.

I was thinking of a `setInterval` which checks a certain number of times a second and move the `<span>` appropriately, however this is both expensive and a dirty trick in my opinion.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Excuse me for oversimplifying, but how about putting them in a wrapper div and only move that wrapper instead of the textarea?

Comment: @mVChr: I'm not a professional at all and I had not thought about that idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you could put the `<span>` and the `<input type="text" />` in the same parent container, such as a `<div>`, then move the `<div>` instead of the `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: This idea had not come to my mind at all - it works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you control the times when the textbox moves, you can also trigger the movement of the span.  If not, then I'm unaware of any events that would work better than your setInterval idea.