# Making an element be exactly behind a sibling element without knowing the position of the sibling element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, flexbox, css-position

I have an input, I want to add a label over the input, but apart from that I have other labels that I want to be displayed on the different CSS events that affect the input.

I use relative positioning to do the overlap effect of the label.

But it leaves a space behind, so then I should probably use absolute positioning.

But I do not know how to know the exact position of the input using pure CSS.

I've seeen this question [Bind the position of an element to another element's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437918/bind-the-position-of-an-element-to-another-elements-position) but I won´t be able to use that because I already use an outer div for my input and also I need to have the input to be siblings to my overlap label, and all the other labels.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.text_input').focus(function(event) {

    $(this).siblings('.text_input_title').addClass('tit_f');
    $(this).siblings('.text_input_real-title').addClass('tirt_f');
    $(this).siblings('.text_input_title').removeClass('tit_b');
    $(this).siblings('.text_input_real-title').removeClass('tirt_b');
  });
  $('.text_input').focusout(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).siblings('.text_input_title').addClass('tit_b');
      $(this).siblings('.text_input_real-title').addClass('tirt_b');
      $(this).siblings('.text_input_title').removeClass('tit_f');
      $(this).siblings('.text_input_real-title').removeClass('tirt_f');
    }
  });


});
```

```css
/*text-input*/

.text_input_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text_input_title {
  z-index: 49;
  position: relative;
  top: 19px;
  order: 2;
  color: #737373;
  transition: .333s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 19px;
}

.text_input_underline {
  order: 1;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: solid 1px #737373;
  transition: .333s;
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: #ad0b0b;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text_input {
  order: 2;
  z-index: 50;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .333s;
  transition: lineal .333s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.text_input_real-title {
  order: 3;
  height: 0px;
  color: #737373;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .333s;
}

.tit_f {
  animation-name: shrink;
  animation-duration: .333s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.tirt_f {
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-delay: .333s;
  animation-duration: .333s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.text_input:focus~.text_input_underline {
  border-top-color: #0b3fad;
}

.text_input:focus~.text_input_real-title {
  color: #0b3fad;
}

.text_input:invalid~.text_input_underline {
  border-top-color: #ad0b0b;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  height: auto;
}

.text_input:invalid~.text_input_real-title {
  color: #ad0b0b;
}

.tit_b {
  height: 0;
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-delay: .333s;
  animation-duration: .333s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.tirt_b {
  animation-name: shrink;
  animation-duration: .333s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
  from {
    height: 19px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 19px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="text_input_div">
    <input type="text" id="init_chat_input" class="text_input" pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z_ ]*">
    <div class="text_input_underline"><span>Only letters, numbers and "_"</span></div>
    <span class="text_input_real-title">Username</span>
    <span class="text_input_title">FUsername</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x20ds4d/2/)**

Comment: In the future, please include the relevant code in the question itself, not only on a third-party website.